# compilation error, Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba, function, compilation

Currently realising a project for my company to highlight anomalies in orders, I wrote this VBA code in order to compare status of orders and a day date difference between the current date and the order date . The dates are as follows on the csv : "2019-05-06 3:11pm"

When I affecte the macro to a button and click on it I get this error : "Compilation error, Sub or function not defined" and the debugger cursor points on "Sub Problem()"...

I hope you can help me!! thanks by advance :)

here is my code :

```
Sub Problem()

Dim orderDate As Date
Dim difDate
Dim statusToUse As Range
Set statusToUse = Range("C2:C100")
Dim statusCell As Range
Dim a As String
a = "accepted"
Dim s As String
s = "shipped"
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim dateToUse As Range
Set dateToUse = Range("D2:D100")
Dim dateCell As Range
Dim currentDate As String
currentDate = Date
y = Split(Split(Range("A1").Value, ":")(1), "-")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each statusCell In statusToUse.Areas
For Each dateCell In dateToUse.Areas

orderDate = DateValue(Join(Array(y(2), y(1), y(0)), "-"))
difDate = DateDiff("d", currentDate, orderDate)

If status = a And difDate <= 7 Then
status.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
i = i + 1

ElseIf status = a And difDate <= 2 Then
status.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
j = j + 1

ElseIf status = a And difDate > 7 Then
status.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
k = k + 1

ElseIf status = s Then
status.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
l = l + 1

Else
m = m + 1

End If

i = i - j

Next dateCell
Next statusCell

MsgBox "There are" + i + "risky orders"

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a lot of errors there... You should use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code (outside the procedure) and try to ident all of this. I tried there but without more info there are many things wrong that I can't correct without know what are you doing.

Comment: If you don't use `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` at the end of your `Sub`, you won't see the results.  Recommend prior to the `MsgBox`.  Same is true for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the sub is in the worksheet and not in a new module.

If it's in a module already, please check if the name of the module is different of "module1".